# Building where clauses?

Tags: clojure, korma, sqlkorma

I would like to be able to build the where clauses for a query. I would like to input a array of where conditions and build the query using korma, as seen below:

```
(defn ^:private fetch-by
  "Append conditions to the query."
  [query ^clojure.lang.PersistentVector conditions]

  (for [condition conditions]
    (if (instance? clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap condition)
      (korma/where query condition) query)))
```

However, the for loop here will duplicate the query object. Is there away to merge these objects or another approach you can recommend that would achieve the desired output?

Comment: not an expert in korma, but seems like `(->> conditions (filter map?) (apply merge) (korma/where query))` should work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *merging* of the `conditions` into one query map can be done with `reduce`:

```
(defn ^:private fetch-by
  "Append conditions to the query."
  [query conditions]
  (->> (filter map? conditions)
       (reduce (fn [query condition]
                 (korma/where query condition))
               query)))
```

Here your initial `reduce` state is whatever `query` you pass in, and the reducing function (and `korma/where`) take care of merging each condition into the query map.

```
(-> (korma/select* :my-table)
    (fetch-by [{:active true}
               {:deleted false}])
    (korma/as-sql))
 => "SELECT \"my-table\".* FROM \"my-table\" WHERE (\"my-table\".\"active\" = ?) AND (\"my-table\".\"deleted\" = ?)"
```

However this is not really different than just passing a single map with multiple entries to `korma/where`:

```
(-> (korma/select* :my-table)
    (korma/where {:active true
                  :deleted false})
    (korma/as-sql))
```

which I would suggest as long as the conditions' keys are unique.

Comment: Thanks for such a detail answer!